# Is there a SQL information_schema XSD definition?

Tags: xml, xsd, information-schema, sql

In [`SQL:2008`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2008), and also previous standards, the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is described as the standard meta-schema. In principle, meta-data could be unloaded into XML for further processing and reverse-engineering of schema meta data with XSLT and other XML tools.

- Has this been done before?
- Is there a somewhat complete XSD available, that describes the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`?

N.B: I'm asking this because I would like to implement unloading of a database schema into a SQL standard `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` XML structure in [jooq-meta](http://www.jooq.org), and then in a second process to load that schema again, to generate Java source code artefacts in jOOQ. For that, I would prefer not to roll my own XSD, but use a pre-existing as-close-to-the-standard-as-possible XSD

Comment: by SQL:2008 do you mean SQL Server?

Comment: @Diego: No I mean the [`SQL:2008`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2008) standard. SQL Server happens to partially implement that standard as far as the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is concerned

Comment: which is the XML schema you need to generate? What requisites does it have? I have not been able to find which is the final schema you need to feed jooq-meta.

Comment: I don't think there is any XML schema defined for SQL's `information_schema`. When looking at the standard's description of the `information_schema` I cannot find any mentioning of XML. It's only defined by the structure of the tables and views (based on SQL). You probably need to "define" your own XML structure.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I know it's not defined in the standard. But maybe someone has done this before and open sourced it, for instance...

Comment: @JotaBe: I don't want to generate an XSD schema. I'd like to use and XSD schema, in order to generate XML. The XML content should be describing a database schema. I updated the question to clarify..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSI/ISO have not defined a particular way of representing a database schema using XML.

The latest standard is SQL:2011.

Here you can see the list of official standards. But, as you can see, they're not free:

[35.060: Languages used in information technology](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_ics/catalogue_ics_browse.htm?ICS1=35&ICS2=60)

Look for ISO/IEC 9075-x in the list. As you can see there's still only the old INFORMATION SCHEMA.

So, your only option is to look for something widely used. Altova has its own way of doing this (a function named "Create XML Schema from DB Structure"). Look at this link:
[How to Convert a Database to an XML Schema](http://www.ehow.com/how_6873762_convert-database-xml-schema.html)

This application has also options to create the database from the exported schema.

I think this is the closest to an standard that you can find (Altova is one of the leading XML software companies. If there was some kind of standard they should know it and use it).

Oxygen XML has also its own way of doing this, and it lloks like there is some kind of "IOS draft":

[Extract XML Schema From a Database Structure](http://www.oxygenxml.com/database_to_schema.html)

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Nice idea, using Altova's products. It may not be free and open source, though. But maybe I can get some ideas...

Comment: I've added the option to do the same in Oxygen. You can look also at schemas used by ORMs like Hibernate, Entity Framework... to catch some ideas. If you look at Embarcadero ER/Studio, you'll also see thath there isn't a stablished standard way of exchanging schema information: http://www.embarcadero.com/products/er-studio/metawizard

Comment: Unfortunately, Hibernate doesn't go very far. It supports no stored procedures, multi-column foreign keys, check constraints, user defined types, arrays, etc etc. I really need the full standard (or my proprietary solution)...